# Why is Bash pattern match for ?(*[[:class:]])foobar slow?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a text file foobar.txt which is around 10KB, not that long.  Yet the following match search command takes about 10 seconds on a high-performance Linux machine.

```
bash>shopt -s extglob
bash>[[ `cat foobar.txt` == ?(*[[:print:]])foobar ]]
```

There is no match:  all the characters in foobar.txt are printable but there is no string "foobar".

The search should try to match two alternatives, each of them will not match:

```
"foobar"
```

that's instantenous

```
*[[:print:]]foobar
```

- which should go like this:

should scan the file character by character in one pass, each time, check if the next characters are

```
[[:print:]]foobar
```

this should also be fast, no way should take a millisecond per character.

In fact, if I drop ?, that is, do

```
bash>[[ `cat foobar.txt` == *[[:print:]]foobar ]]
```

this **is** instantaneous.  But this is simply the second alternative above, without the first.

So why is this so long??

Comment: You should consider using special utilities for stuff like that. Like ``grep``, ``sed`` or ``awk``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have noted, you're probably better off using `grep`.

That said, if you wanted to stick with a `[[` conditional - combining @konsolebox and @rici's advice - you'd get:

```
[[ $(<foobar.txt)  =~ (^|[[:print:]])foobar$ ]]
```

Edit: Regex updated to match the OP's requirements - thanks, @rici.

Generally speaking, it is preferable to use *regular expressions* for string matching (via the `=~` operator, in this case), rather than [globbing] *patterns* (via the `==` operator), whose primary purpose is matching file- and folder names.

Comment: Actually, looking at your pattern made me realize that I hadn't written the regex correctly in my answer. But yours is not correct: he wants to either match a string consisting entirely of `foobar` or a string which ends with a printable character followed by `foobar`. In your regex, `[[:print:]]?` could be removed completely by a good regex optimizer, because it makes no difference to any possible match.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, the answer is that == does not do the kind of pattern matching that for example Perl does, it appears to be "dumb".  The solution is to simply use =~ which is "smart".  Indeed, using =~ with any kind of pattern like the above, is fast.

Answer (score 7):

The glob matcher in bash is just not optimized. See, for example, [this bug-bash thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2013-04/msg00099.html), during which bash maintainer Chet Ramey says:

> It's not a regexp engine, it's an interpreted-on-the-fly matcher.

Since bash includes a regexp engine as well (use `=~` instead of `==` inside `[[ ]]`), there's probably not much motivation to do anything about it.

On my machine, the equivalent regexp (`^(.*[[:print:]])?foobar$`) suffered considerably from locale-aware `[[:print:]]`; for some reason, that didn't affect the glob matcher. Setting LANG=C made the regexp work fine.

However, for a string that size, I'd use grep.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because you do many forks of bash (one for the subshell, and one for the cat command), and also, you read the cat binary as well while you execute it.

```
[[ `cat foobar.txt` == *[[:print:]]foobar ]]
```

This form would be faster:

```
[[ $(<foobar.txt) == *[[:print:]]foobar ]]
```

Or

```
IFS= read -r LINE < foobar.txt && [[ $LINE == *[[:print:]]foobar ]]
```

If it doesn't make a difference the speed of pattern matching could be related to the version of Bash you're using.

Comment: Thank you but, you are missing the "?" character .  That is crucial, without that, everything is fast.  That is exactly my point in fact, why "?" matters.

Comment: It's really hard to believe that replacing `cat` with a builtin equivalent would save more than a few microseconds.

Comment: @rici When command paths and binaries aren't cached yet it certainly will and would vary depending on the IO speed.