# Are = and =~ equivalent to check simple regular expressions?

Tags: regex, bash

Reading a [comment by Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869838/bash-efficient-file-parsing/37869927#comment63219569_37869927) I ran across a question: is there any difference in using `=` or `=~` to check simple regular expressions?

When we just want to check if a string is part of another string, these options are equivalent:

```
$ [[ hello = *el* ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ hello =~ el ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

Same happens if the store the regular expression in a variable:

```
$ re="[0-9]"
$ number=2
$ [[ $number = $re ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ $number = *$re* ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

However, checking non-literal strings does not work with `=` and needs the usage of `=~`:

```
$ date=20160620
$ [[ $date = [0-9]{4}(0[0-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) ]] && echo "yes"
bash: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `('
bash: syntax error near `[0-9]{4}(0'
$ [[ $date =~ [0-9]{4}(0[0-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1]) ]] && echo "yes"
yes
$ [[ $date =~ ^[0-9]{4}(0[0-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$ ]] && echo "yes"
yes
```

What should be used in general performance and POSIX-wise?

Note all of these occurs is based on my `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: Thats difference between globbing and Regex. `=` uses globbing whereas `=~` uses Regex.

Comment: If you have a choice, prefer regex for efficiency; it's usually faster. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18412294/1566221. But regex aren't posix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only glob pattern matching is supported using `=` and `==` in BASH.

Your first 2 examples are producing the same result because you are matching `*el*` (glob) in first and `el` (will be same in glob or regex or plain string) in 2nd example.

But when you use proper regex using character classes, quantifiers, anchors etc then you must use `=~` only to match a regular expression.

That is precisely the reason of syntax error in 2nd block because shell is trying to interpret given regex as a glob pattern.

---

From [Bash Reference Manual → 3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> ```
> [[ expression ]]
> ```
>
> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of
>   the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the
>   rules described below in [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), as if the `extglob`
>   shell option were enabled. The ‘=’ operator is identical to ‘==’.
>
> An additional binary operator, ‘=~’, is available, with the same
>   precedence as ‘==’ and ‘!=’. When it is used, the string to the right
>   of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and
>   matched accordingly (as in regex3)).

Comment: Oh, nice! From [Bash reference manual - 3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs), _=~ (...) When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly_, whereas _When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching, as if the extglob shell option were enabled_. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes that's right `=`, `!=` and `==` also support extended glob patterns

Comment: OK, now it is clear then. If you don't mind I will add the references in your answer, so it is complete to be accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Yes please feel free to add them in answer.